# Problem in downloading model

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When i am trying to load any model in gazebo from the insert tab using the link i am getting the following error.
Can sm1 tell what may b the problem...?

```
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:354] Unable to load manifest                  
file[/home/myname/.gazebo/models/bookshelf/manifest.xml]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:391] Invalid model manifest 
file[/home/myname/.gazebo/models/bookshelf/manifest.xml]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/122/problem-in-downloading-model./) by [Vipul Divyanshu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/71/vipul-divyanshu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try deleting '/home/myname/.gazebo/models/bookshelf', and then try again. You probably have an outdated manifest.xml file.

If that doesn't work, can you post the contents of the manifest file?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0